# Single class library project for .NET and .NET Core projects

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

Is it possible to create a simple class library project with Visual Studio that can get referenced by both .NET and .NET core projects?

I tried creating a class library project (a project for creating a class library that targets .net standard and .net core) but it wouldn't let me add as a reference to the .net project.

I then created a class library for .NET framework (A project for creating a C# class library .dll), which I could add as a reference to both projects but failed to run on linux os.

The only nugget package I've included on the common project is Newtonsoft.Json (13.0.1)

Solution Properties:

- .NET framework project: 4.5 (WebAPI)
- .NET core project: 5.0 (MVC razor)
- .NET framework class library: 4.5

Comment: With .NET Framework 4.5, the newest .NET Standard version you can use is 1.0 ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)). Is there any chance you could update to a newer framework version? If that's not possible, perhaps you could create a Shared Library and then have separate .NET Standard and .NET Framework projects for it?

Comment: Hello @Llama, I would have to check how old the server is and what's latest version it can support. But I can't see my .NET Core version on that chart (.NET 5.0), is there a .net framework version that could support it?

Comment: .NET Core has transitioned into .NET 5 going forwards, so it's on the row above .NET Core in the chart.

Comment: @Llama All of the cells of the `.NET` row have the value `5.0`. Doesn't that mean it's compatible with .NET framework `4.5`?

Comment: If you have the source for the .NET 4.5 WebAPI then you could open that, tell it to target 4.7.2 or above, rebuild and retest?  That would then get you .NET Standard 2.0 support, which you could target with the shared library.

Comment: Blurb above the chart: _"The following table lists the minimum implementation versions that support each .NET Standard version. That means that later versions of a listed implementation also support the corresponding .NET Standard version."_ - the chart shows what supports what version of .NET Standard. That's it.

Comment: @cjb110 I updated the project version, but now none of the references (i.e. system, system.data ...) load properly, do I have to remove each one and then add them again or is there a faster way to fix them?

Comment: @nickzoum can't remember having to do that, a clean rebuild should sort things.

Comment: @cjb110 Thanks for the help, it works now. I've added an answer in case somebody else also has the same question

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by recreating the .NET project with .NET framework 4.7.2 (references wouldn't load properly by just changing the version), and also recreating the common library using .NET standard 2.0.

Thanks for the help cjb110 and Llama.